# How to clone a <div> element containing a form without the values?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to duplicate a  element that contains part of a HTML form. I already got it to work, but can't manage to clone that part without the values typed in the one that is being cloned. I show my code below.

```js
    document.getElementById('showmore').onclick = duplicate;
    var i = 1;
    var original = document.getElementById('fieldset1');
    var boton = document.getElementById("showmore");

    function duplicate() {
      if (i = 1) {
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
        clone.id = "fieldset" + ++i;
        original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, boton.previousSibling);
      }
    }
```

```html
<div id='fieldset1'>
      <hr>
      <div class='control-group form-group'>
        <div class='controls'>
          <label>Cause</label>
          <textarea name='cause[]' maxlength='100' class='form-control' required></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='control-group form-group'>
        <div class='controls'>
          <label>Effect</label>
          <textarea name='effect[]' maxlength='100' class='form-control' required></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='control-group form-group'>
        <div class='controls'>
          <label>Knowledge</label>
          <textarea name='knowledge[]' maxlength='300' class='form-control'></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class='control-group form-group'>
        <div class='controls'>
          <label>Actions</label>
          <textarea name='actions[]' maxlength='300' class='form-control'></textarea>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <button type='button' onlick='duplicate()' class='btn btn-warning' id='showmore'> Add more</button>
```

Comment: can you provide runable  html snippet.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want the text within the `textarea`'s to be cloned? :)

Comment: please remove jquery tag, your question does not relates to jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two option one is to manually empty the value after the clone, which is unnecessary.
secound is to make a default clone at first run, se the code below.

```js
document.getElementById('showmore').onclick = duplicate;
var i = 1;
var original = document.getElementById('fieldset1');
var boton = document.getElementById("showmore");
// make an empty default clonad form 
// before the user type anything
var emptyForm = original.cloneNode(true);

function duplicate() {
  if (i = 1) {
    // then only clone this empty form
    var clone = emptyForm.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "fieldset" + ++i;
            original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone,boton.previousSibling);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='fieldset1'>
  <hr>
  <div class='control-group form-group'>
    <div class='controls'>
      <label>Cause</label>
      <textarea name='cause[]' maxlength='100' class='form-control' required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='control-group form-group'>
    <div class='controls'>
      <label>Effect</label>
      <textarea name='effect[]' maxlength='100' class='form-control' required></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='control-group form-group'>
    <div class='controls'>
      <label>Knowledge</label>
      <textarea name='knowledge[]' maxlength='300' class='form-control'></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='control-group form-group'>
    <div class='controls'>
      <label>Actions</label>
      <textarea name='actions[]' maxlength='300' class='form-control'></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

<button type='button' onlick='duplicate()' class='btn btn-warning' id='showmore'> Add more</button>
```

Comment: Very elegant approach! I like this :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick! You also want to iterate over all the `<textarea>` elements in the new form and remove their values.

```
var i = 1;
var original = document.getElementById('fieldset1');
var boton = document.getElementById("showmore");
boton.onclick = function(){
    if(i == 1){ // also, it should be 'i == 1' not 'i = 1' :)
        var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
        clone.id = "fieldset" + i++;

        var textarea = clone.getElementsByTagName("textarea");
        for(var j = 0; j < textarea.length; j++)
            textarea[j].value= "";

        original.parentNode.insertBefore(clone, boton.previousSibling);
    }
}
```